# Why iptables rule to limit packet 2048/s becomes 2500/sec when listed out?

Tags: linux, iptables

I created the following IPtables rule:

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -m limit --limit 2048/s -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j RATE-LIMIT
```

When I list out the rule with the command `iptables -L`, the output was shown as:

```
RATE-LIMIT  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:123 limit: avg 2500/sec burst 5 ctstate NEW
```

Why the limit that I put as 2048/second become 2500/second?

I have searched the Internet but cannot find any resource that can explain the behaviour.